# Java Programming Error: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, concurrentmodification

I'm writing a program as part of tutorial for a beginner Java student.  I have the following method and whenever I run it, it gives me the following exception:

```
  java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
        at Warehouse.receive(Warehouse.java:48)
        at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:13)
```

Here's the method itself, within the class Warehouse:

```
public void receive(MusicMedia product, int quantity) {

  if ( myCatalog.size() != 0) { // Checks if the catalog is empty

    // if the catalog is NOT empty, it will run through looking to find
    // similar products and add the new product if there are none
    for (MusicMedia m : myCatalog) { 
        if ( !m.getSKU().equals(product.getSKU()) ) {
                myCatalog.add(product);
        }
    }

  } else { // if the catalog is empty, just add the product
        myCatalog.add(product);
  }
}
```

The problem seems to be with the if else statement.  If I don't include the if else, then the program will run, although it won't work properly because the loop won't iterate through an empty ArrayList.

I've tried adding a product just to keep it from being empty in other parts of the code, but it still gives me the same error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not modify `mCatalog` while you're iterating over it. You're adding an element to it in this loop:

```
for (MusicMedia m : myCatalog) { 
    if ( !m.getSKU().equals(product.getSKU()) ) {
            myCatalog.add(product);
    }
}
```

See [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) and [modCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#modCount) in [AbstractList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, staring at the code too long seemed to make me forget about that part.

Answer (score 6):

You can't be iterating through the same list you're going to add things to. Keep a separate list of the things you're going to add, then add them all at the end.

Comment: So it doesn't matter that the iteration and the adding aren't happening at the same time? (separated by the if else)

Comment: You can't modify a collection while you're iterating over it. That is the cause of **any** `ConcurrentModificationException` in Java.

Comment: @user1104775 it does not matter. You cannot modify a collection inside an iteration loop.

Comment: I seemed to be focusing too much on the second add I forgot about the first one within the loop.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1104775 What do you mean, not iterating and adding at the same time? Everything that happens between for (...) { and the closing } has the open iterator created using MusicMedia m : myCatalog in scope. It's the myCatalog.add(...) in the if (!m.getSku()...) which is a concurrent modification. - ah you noticed so yourself :)